# Convert from timestamp to time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I am trying to display a time using timestamp. An example is below:

```
t = Time.at(1500999892331)
#=> 49534-10-18 04:02:11 +0530
t.to_date
#=> Thu, 18 Oct 49534
```

I am getting a wrong output. Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: Which part is wrong, and what is the "correct" output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby's [`Time.at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Time.html#method-c-at) expects seconds (with fraction). Per the definition

> Creates a new Time object with the value given by time, the given number of `seconds_with_frac`, or `seconds` and `microseconds_with_frac` since the Epoch.

The value you provided is milliseconds. Change it to

```
Time.at(1500999892331/1000)
=> 2017-07-25 21:54:52 +0530
t.to_date
=> Tue, 25 Jul 2017
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this

```
(Time.at(1500999892331/1000)+0530).strftime("%I:%M%p")
#=> "10:00PM"
```

or

```
(Time.at(1500999892331/1000)+0530).strftime("%Y-%b-%d %I:%M%p")
#=> "2017-Jul-25 10:00PM"
```

Following are some of the Date and Time formats that you could specify in `strftime` method:

```
Date (Year, Month, Day):
  %Y - Year with century (can be negative, 4 digits at least)
          -0001, 0000, 1995, 2009, 14292, etc.
  %C - year / 100 (round down.  20 in 2009)
  %y - year % 100 (00..99)

  %m - Month of the year, zero-padded (01..12)
          %_m  blank-padded ( 1..12)
          %-m  no-padded (1..12)
  %B - The full month name (``January'')
          %^B  uppercased (``JANUARY'')
  %b - The abbreviated month name (``Jan'')
          %^b  uppercased (``JAN'')
  %h - Equivalent to %b

  %d - Day of the month, zero-padded (01..31)
          %-d  no-padded (1..31)
  %e - Day of the month, blank-padded ( 1..31)

  %j - Day of the year (001..366)

Time (Hour, Minute, Second, Subsecond):
  %H - Hour of the day, 24-hour clock, zero-padded (00..23)
  %k - Hour of the day, 24-hour clock, blank-padded ( 0..23)
  %I - Hour of the day, 12-hour clock, zero-padded (01..12)
  %l - Hour of the day, 12-hour clock, blank-padded ( 1..12)
  %P - Meridian indicator, lowercase (``am'' or ``pm'')
  %p - Meridian indicator, uppercase (``AM'' or ``PM'')

  %M - Minute of the hour (00..59)

  %S - Second of the minute (00..59)

  %L - Millisecond of the second (000..999)
  %N - Fractional seconds digits, default is 9 digits (nanosecond)
          %3N  millisecond (3 digits)
          %6N  microsecond (6 digits)
          %9N  nanosecond (9 digits)
          %12N picosecond (12 digits)
```

Comment: How can I get the date here?

Comment: @ShruthiR answer updated please check